# Jquery loading up a script twice issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function which loads up relevant js functions on click using ajax's shorthand [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

It looks like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    $.getScript('/script.js');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/file.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#window').html(data);
        }
     });

});
```

This works okay... until I click #button again and getScript loads script.js again meaning that any functions inside script.js get triggered not once, but twice.

[In another thread somebody mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711443/questions-about-jquerys-getscript/2711453#2711453) this is a cacheing issue and that since $.getScript() is merely shorthand for $.ajax() *and* that **by default ajax requests do not cache scripts** that one should do the long version with 'cache: *true*'.

So I tried:

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'script.js',
      dataType: 'script',
      cache: true,
      success: function(data) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/file.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#window').html(data);
            }
         });

      }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I am still in the same boat and every time I click #button all my functions in script.js are being appended again and again.

What is one to do? How do you go about loading a script just once, and/or checking to see if the resource is already loaded and if so, don't bother loading it all again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// in the scope of a doc ready so `loaded` isnt global:

```
var loaded = false;

$('#button').click(function() {

    if ( !loaded ) {
        $.getScript('/script.js', function() {
             loaded = true;
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/file.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#window').html(data);
        }
     });

});
```

Comment: I see. I am humbled by the simplicity and obviousness of this solution.

Comment: if the second ajax request needs to happen only after `script.js` is loaded, throw it in the first callback function which has `loaded = true`.